# ionic run android : doesn't detect the android platform on windows

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, platform

I want to run the `ionic run android` command using the id of my device, but I keep on getting an error about the android platform, I already removed it and added it again but it doesn't work, I have no idea what I'm missing, if it's a dependency or what, I would appreciate your help...

Your system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1 
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.1 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.1 
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.1 
OS: Node Version: v6.8.0
```

> Usuario@DESKTOP-R2IE3CM MINGW64 ~/teenteras/teenteras (master) $ ionic
>   platform Installed platforms: android 5.2.2 browser 4.1.0 ios 4.2.1
>   windows 4.4.2 Available platforms: amazon-fireos ~3.6.3 (deprecated)
>   blackberry10 ~3.8.0 firefoxos ~3.6.3 webos ~3.7.0 wp8 ~3.8.2
>   (deprecated)

this is the error:

> Usuario@DESKTOP-R2IE3CM MINGW64 ~/teenteras/teenteras (master) $ ionic
>   run android A013ADFD2AD4BCB8 • You're trying to build for android but
>   don't have the platform installed yet. ∆ Installing android for you.
>   Installing cordova-plugin-device Installing cordova-plugin-console
>   Installing cordova-plugin-whitelist Installing
>   cordova-plugin-splashscreen Installing cordova-plugin-statusbar
>   Installing ionic-plugin-keyboard  Error: Command failed: cordova
>   platform add android
>   C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
>                       throw e;
>                       ^
>
> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename
>   'C:\Users\Usuario.config\configstore\update-notifier-cordova.json.4102744267'
>   -> 'C:\Users\Usuario.config\configstore\update-notifier-cordova.json'
>       at Error (native)
>       at Object.fs.renameSync (fs.js:809:18)
>       at Function.writeFileSync [as sync] (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\write-file-atomic\index.js:81:8)
>       at Object.set (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\configstore\index.js:62:21)
>       at Object.Configstore (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\configstore\index.js:27:11)
>       at new UpdateNotifier (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\update-notifier\index.js:34:17)
>       at module.exports (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\update-notifier\index.js:123:23)
>       at checkForUpdates (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\cli.js:67:24)
>       at cli (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\cli.js:246:5)
>       at C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\cli.js:143:16
>
> ```
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)
> at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
> at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
> ```

Comment: do **npm install** first.. then try to add platform

Comment: Does ionic build android work for you? 
Try doing everything from scratch...like from here https://ionicframework.com/getting-started/

Comment: I checked everything again, and moving the project to another folder with a diferent name did the thing, I guess it was having trouble with that, thanks for your help.